# How can I unit test code which uses a confluent_kafka Consumer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest, confluent-kafka-python

I'm trying to unit test the following piece of code using pytest:

```
import json
from typing import Any, Dict

from confluent_kafka import Consumer


def get_message(config: Dict[str, Any]):
    consumer = Consumer(
        {
            "group.id": config["KAFKA_GROUP_ID"],
            "bootstrap.servers": config["KAFKA_BROKERS"],
            "default.topic.config": {"auto.offset.reset": "smallest"},
        }
    )
    consumer.subscribe([config["KAFKA_TOPIC"]])
    while True:
        collect = consumer.poll()
        if collect is None:
            continue

        try:
            message = json.loads(collect.value().decode("utf-8"))
        except json.JSONDecodeError:
            continue

        return message
```

But I can't mock subscribe function. I tried:

```
mock_subscribe = MagicMock(return_value='test')
monkeypatch.setattr('confluent_kafka.cimpl.Consumer.subscribe', mock_subscribe)
```

In result I got following error:

```
TypeError: can't set attributes of built-in/extension type
```

How to mock this function properly?

Comment: Ok, so I can't mock this because of the implementation of this function in C/C++

Comment: Yes, unfortunately. But you can create a simple Python class that wraps `Consumer` class (with same merthods calling original methods) and use it instead of the original one. This Python class you can mock then.

Comment: This is not a duplicate.